# Pixelated screen and Death

Tags: 8.1, display

Sometimes my phone hangs. When I try to lock and unlock it, the result is a pixelated screen (see similar picture below) and my only option is to restart the phone.

What is the cause of this issue and is there any solution for it?

[image: Pixelated Screen]

Comment: This is a Q&A site. What is your question?

Comment: What phone do you have?

Comment: @VivekParekh, Lumia 620

Comment: I'd suggest taking it to a Nokia service centre (or the store you got it from, if under warranty), as it looks like it may be a hardware fault

Comment: @RowlandShaw, nop i think, because my handset got replaced just one month ago. I had the same problem with old phone too. This is happening once or twice in a month. Using 8.1 update.

Comment: Are you using running the dev preview, or the Cyan release?

Comment: Developer Preview. Cyan update is not available at here yet.

Comment: You can always use the Nokia Software Recovery Tool to rollback to Windows Phone Os 8. Have you tried this?

Comment: So this is a stumped one... :|
There's a similar (random) issue. The phone display is getting high (very high) contrasted.

Answer (score 3):

There's a thread on the forums of WPCentral that seems like a similar issue: [**Screen Pixelated**](http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-920/230109-screen-pixelated.html). Here are several options you have:

- **Check for any updates for your device**
- **Do a hard reset, this can be done in two ways:**

  *1. Through the interface:*

  - Navigate to settings
  - Tap `about`
  - Tap `reset your phone`
  - Confirm by tapping `yes`

  *2. Hardware buttons*

  - Switch off your phone
  - Press and hold Camera + Power + Volume Down buttons
  - After few seconds, the phone will vibrate
  - Release the Power button alone holding the Camera and Volume Down button
  - After 5 to 10 seconds release both the buttons
- **Send your phone back to Nokia or the store where you bought it**

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue about half an hour ago. I tried turning it off and it wouldn't work. I tried plugging it into my laptop to see if anything will show up on the file only to find that the folder was empty. Reading the previous person's response actually reminded me to try a soft reset. I just did it and my phone seems to be working normally.

I previously had a blue screen that said "PROCESS1 INITIALIZATION FAILED"- this is where I learned to soft reset the phone.

To do a soft reset you hold down the power button with the volume down button for 10 seconds. The phone will restart itself and you won't (or shouldn't) lose any data.

I know your post was from August 2014, but I hope this helps anyone else with this issue that doesn't want to hard reset their phone.